# How to pass a variable within a powershell string with escaped double qoutes

Tags: powershell

I'm new to powershell and I need to pass my variable in this string, but I think since I am escaping the double quotes it's not passing my variable value.

```
$A = 'test@email.com'
$B ='{
  \"merchant_info\": {
  \"email\": \" $A \",
  }'
write-host $B
```

Comment: It looks like you are also trying to write json. You can do something similar to @{"merchant_info"=@{"email"=$A}} | convertto-json which will get you all the correct formatting without having to worry about escaping single or double quotes

Comment: It's because you're using single quoted strings; PowerShell doesn't interpolate variables in single quoted strings, only double quoted ones. And backslash is not a powershell string escape character, backtick is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to escape character `, you also can use either of following options.

**Using *Here-Strings***

```
$B =
@"
{
    "merchant_info": {
        "email": "$A"
    }
}
"@
```

**Using *ConvertTo-Json***

```
$B = @{"merchant_info" = @{"email" = $A} } | ConvertTo-Json
```

**Using Two `"`**

```
$B = "{""merchant_info"": {""email"": ""$A"" } }"
```

Answer (score 4):

Escape double quotes in Powershell by doing `"

So to make your code work, change it to the following:

```
$A = 'test@email.com'
$B ="{`"merchant_info`": {`"email`":  `"$A`",}"
write-host $B
```